# How can you see what file type intellij thinks your current file is?

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea

My auto-formatting in intellij is not working on my *.spec.ts files, but it does in my *.ts files.  I added the *.spec.ts to the typescript file type matchers, but that didn't help. I'm assuming intellij thinks the file belongs to a different file type, but I don't know what that might be.

How can I tell what file type intellij thinks the file is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Override File Language](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7404-override-file-language) plug-in show the current file type in the status bar and allows changing it.

[image: file type]